# Using tardigrades as space shielding

Tags: shielding

Since tardigrades are almost extremophilic, and so are [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinococcus_radiodurans), should we use them as shielding material? A thick enough layer outside the spacecraft will shield it and we may use breeding techniques so that the shield is automatically renewed.

Comment: Why not just use the *tardigrade food* itself as shielding. and avoid the middleman?

Comment: It will degrade.

Comment: Shielding against what?

Comment: Bio-organisms are messy, and probably less efficient shielding than e.g. polystyrene or water.

Comment: @Organic Marble micrometeoroids, radiation.

Comment: @Hobbes yeah, but they also renew themselves.

Comment: There isn’t necessarily a connection between being resistant to harm from radiation and stopping radiation.

Comment: And iirc they survive extremes by suspended animation so not much replication to happen.

Comment: Well, the shield is thick and renewed, unlike metals. @jkavalik that true?

Comment: It's our DNA that would need renewing, even better such than what we have evolved on Earth. Then we wouldn't need any shielding. The radiation doesn't care if it hits a molecule in a dead or a living tardigrade, the shield needs no renewing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This would not be very feasible.** There are several reasons. First, living creatures are unpredictable and uncontrollable.  How could you be sure that all your tardigrades would maintain an even layer across the ship?  What if they chose to all group up at one location?

Second, because tardigrades are not as dense as, say, a sheet of iron, you would need to have an extremely thick layer of them to provide adequate shielding.

Third, in order to survive extremely harsh climates, tardigrades undergo a [form of stasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade#Physiology) where they suspend all metabolic processes. So they would not be reproducing at all. And even though they have extremely high survivability, studies where tardigrades were exposed to outer space for 10 days yielded a [~30% mortality rate](http://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(08)00805-1?_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0960982208008051%3Fshowall%3Dtrue).  So you would still have lots of them die.

Finally, even if they did maintain their metabolic processes, you would still need to provide enough food for them to survive and reproduce. So you'd need to have even more material sent up. Moreover, while tardigrades can survive extremely high doses of radiation, tardigrade eggs exposed to radiation have [extremely low hatch rates](http://www.jlimnol.it/index.php/jlimnol/article/view/750).

Ultimately, this plan would be extremely complicated, not very useful, and not have any real advantages.